# Externally running Python Script as module : ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

So far I successfully run my Blender Python scripts externally in the PyCharm-IDE like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

However if I try to run the script ***iso.py*** as module via the external script ***render_buildings.py*** I get an error :

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iso'
```

[image]

The module ***iso.py*** is actually in the same directory as the called script ***render_buildings.py*** and it also contains an empty **init**.py script like the Python specification demands.

How to fix it, any ideas ?

Comment: there are 2 python versions on your computer, one "normal", one "inside" Blender. If you are using a python lib, you have to install it inside Blender. A tutorial is here: https://youtu.be/2zGIERHU2mk?si=q9mFRNVL3RGCmoca

Comment: @Chris unfortunately the script does not work on my windows system as it was written und tested originally for MacOs. But at least I have an idea why this would not work.

Comment: so your pycharm IDE run on a Mac?

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'python_exe' referenced before assignment
 and  
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sys' referenced before assignment

Comment: Pycharm and blender both run on Windows

Comment: This simple python script in blender worked for me:
`
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'iso'])
`